# Inequality $(x^2 + 3x + 1)\cdot(x^2 + 3x - 3) \geq 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

This is the question I have in front of me. Clearly, I need to find the range of values of $x$ for the given inequality.

Having taken a cue from a similar question, here's how I approached it -

Let $ a = x^2 + 3x + 1$
$\implies ax^2 + 3ax - (3a + 5) \geq 0$

Now, for this quadratic expression to be greater than or equal to $0$, the coefficient of $x^2$ must be $>0$, with the discriminant being equal to $0$. But, the coefficient of $x^2$ i.e. $a = x^2 + 3x + 1$ can take negative values also, which does not ensure the requirement.

So, how shall I go about this one? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just a note I had to use inspect in my browser just to get into this question

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}\text{Is this a question which I see before me,}\cr
\text{The handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee.}\cr
\text{I have thee not, and yet I see thee still.}\cr
\text{Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible}\cr
\text{To feeling as to sight? Or art thou but}\cr
\text{A question of the mind, a false creation,}\cr
\text{Proceeding from the heat-oppressèd brain?}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

not quite. Let
$$ b = x^2 + 3 x - 1 $$
$$ (b+2)(b - 2) \geq 5 $$
$$ b^2 \geq 9 $$
$$ b \leq -3 \; \; \mbox{OR} \; \; b \geq 3 $$

Comment: Well, the answer comes out to be a null set. Thanks @WillJagy. That was of great help.

Comment: @Saksham it is not a null set. Get some graph paper and carefully graph $y = x^2 + 3x + 2$ and then $y = x^2 +3x-4$ ... https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: Yeah I realised that soon after writing the comment, but forgot to make the amends here.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Observe that if

$$f (x)=(x^2+3x+1)(x^2+3x-3) $$

then $$f (1)=f (-1)=f (-2)=f (-4)=5$$
thus

$$f (x)-5=$$
$$(x-1)(x+1)(x+2)(x+4) $$

Comment: This solution is really elegant, even more than the other solution. +1

Comment: @JohnLou Thanks a lot for this.:).